# How to fix Select2 android search problem?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

On select2, the search works fine on desktop and iOS, but on android, when the cursor is placed in the search field, the select closes. **I need to keep the ability to search on mobile**

I tried setting closeOnSelect: false, it doesn't help.

```
$("select").select2({
   minimumResultsForSearch: 5,
   closeOnSelect: false
})
```